# How to speed up my Ajax call when there are multiple same ajax call made on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the page loads, I am also dynamically creating a block . I am using ajax call to go and fetch data from another page and then populating it and creating my structure that is then added to a particular dom element. However, the problem is when I do this several times on the page during page loads, it takes quite some time for all Ajax call to finish. Do you know how I can speed up the ajax call?

```
      $('.content-tile').each(function (idx, ele) {

    // Step 1: Get the stuffs and add it in the right place on page load
    var node_id = $(ele).find('article').attr('data-history-node-id');
    $.get('/node/' + node_id , function (data) {

      var $title = $(data).find('.title').text();
      var $summary = $(data).find('.article__body').text();
      var $ctaText = $(data).find('.article__field-read-more-text').text();

      var $redirectToFile = $(data).find('.article__field-nova-redirect-to-file').find('a').attr('href');
      var $redirectToLink = $(data).find('.article__field-redirect-link').find('a').attr('href');

      // Either redirect to file or redirect to link in the order
      var $ctaLinkHref = $redirectToFile;
      if ($redirectToLink) {
        $ctaLinkHref = $redirectToLink;
      }

      var $contentHover = "<a class='content-added contenthover hoveredLink' href= " + $ctaLinkHref + "></a>";
      $(ele).find('article').after($contentHover); // Add the div that will be targeted for the hover

      var $contentHoverHeader = "<h2 class='contenthover__header'>" + $title + '</h2>';
      var $contentHoverContent = "<p class='contenthover__content'>" + $summary + '</p>';


      var $contentHoverLink = "<a class='contenthover__link' href=" + $ctaLinkHref + '>' + $ctaText + '</a>';

      $(ele).find('.contenthover').append($contentHoverHeader, $contentHoverContent, $contentHoverLink);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Instead of making multiple calls, make one call that gets all data.

Comment: That is not actually possible for my case. Because the page actually adds multiple blocks of "elements" that editors adds from backend of the cms. These elements then uses my js ajax to make the calls.Each of these elements links to separate article pages. The ajax calls basically goes and gets data from these article pages and populates.

Comment: Well if you have to make multiple calls then the only option is to optimise your server side code to respond faster, or buy more/faster servers. By making multiple calls you're effectively DDOS-ing yourself

Comment: hmm you are right... I will look into the server side it.. Actually you are right in terms of DDOs-ing.. Now I feel like shit!

Answer (score 1):

As Rory mentioned, instead of calling multiple times, just create the single object, post it back and return all the related data in one go.

```
// construct the array
var nodes = []
 $('.content-tile').each(function (idx, ele) {
  var node_id = $(ele).find('article').attr('data-history-node-id');
  nodes.push(node_id);
}

// call ajax now
$.ajax({
  url: "/node/RetrieveDataByNodes", //the new method which can accept the array and return data
  data: JSON.stringify(nodes),
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(result) {
  $.each(result, function (k, v) {
     //do something for each value
     console.log(v);
  }
});
```